# Tables not found when hive cli called from different directory

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am facing a weird problem with Hive Tables. I have `HIVE_HOME` set in my environ and it is also in my search path so i can invoke `hive` directly.

Now I invoke `hive` from a directory lets say `/a/b/c` and create some tables. I can see the tables.

Now I change to a directory e.g `/a/b` and invoke `hive` from there. Here is the problem part. Either i am unable to see the tables or i get this error

```
hive> show tables;
FAILED: Error in metadata: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Failed to start    
database 'metastore_db', see the next exception for details.

NestedThrowables:
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db', see the next exception    
for details.
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Why are tables tied to the directory from which the `hive` cli was called from? Any pointers?

Comment: Please verify the below link, it might help.

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735843/create-table-exception-in-hive>

Comment: @RamanaUppala, No its not the same problem.

Comment: The tables are visible from the directory when hive is launched from the same directory. But not visible when hive is launched from other directories

Comment: Resolved by the reference to the solution given by Ramana

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using derby server which hive uses for storing the metadata. So, for that what you can do is delete everything inside metastore_db folder and then try to restart the hadoop. And then try to see. But, i think best advice would be you use the mysql as a metastore.

Comment: In future you will again have the problem of this metadata exception. For time being you will be able to query through hive. So use mysql as a metastore and set the appropriate uri in hive-site.xml (javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL). And why did you do -1. kindly give the justification?